# Subtract from cell reference

Tags: excel, vba, reference

I just need a way to remove two from a cell reference (i.e changing =Y36 to =Y34) This needs to be done on the two cells just before the end of a column and the closest I have come to it is

```
Sub Update_Reference()

     Dim myCell  As Range

    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2).Resize(2).Select
    For Each myCell In Selection
        If myCell.HasFormula Then myCell.Formula = Left(myCell.Formula, _
                                                Len(myCell.Formula) - 1) & 4
    Next myCell
 
End Sub
```

But that only appeared to work; all it seemed to do was copy the same formula to each additional cell

Comment: "But that only appeared to work" ... don't leave us in suspense.

Comment: The code sort of works.  If I put formulas in **A1** through **A14**, the code changes **A12** and **A13**.  It replaces the last character in the formulas with the character *4*.  Is that not what you want ??

Comment: Note:  replacing a character by *4* is not the same as subtracting *2* from a number.

Comment: I simply want to take the reference in the cell and make it two less. The reference would change each time this is needed, so that wouldn't fit my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Sub Update_Reference()

     Dim myCell  As Range, s As String, i As Long, N As Long
     Dim FirstPart As String

    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-2).Resize(2).Select
    
    For Each myCell In Selection
        If myCell.HasFormula Then
            s = myCell.Formula
            For i = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
                If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then
                '
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            
            FirstPart = Mid(s, 1, i)
            N = Mid(s, i + 1) - 2
            myCell.Formula = FirstPart & N
        End If
    Next myCell
 
End Sub
```

**NOTES:**

The code breaks the formula into 2 parts; the number part at the end of the formula *(N)* and everything else *(FirstPart)* .It subtracts *2* from the number part and puts the formula back together.

Comment: Looking at that formula shows how above my knowledge of VBA this was. Thanks for your assistance; that does work

Comment: @Hebert  I added **NOTES**